# How can I get an object from ngrx-store

Tags: angular, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

How can I get an object from ngrx-store?

I'm trying to do this

```
<div class="container">
      <h1>
          {{category$.name}}
      </h1>
</div>
```

**Component**

```
export class CatalogViewController {
private routeSubscription: Subscription;
private uri: string;

category$: Observable<any>;

constructor(
    private store: Store<fromRoot.State>,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private titleService: Title
) {
    this.routeSubscription = route.params.subscribe(params=>this.uri = params['uri']);
    this.store.dispatch(new catalogActions.LoadCategory({"uri": this.uri}));

    this.category$ = store.select(fromRoot.getCategory);
   }
}
```

Data in the store is available

**Store**

```
catalog: {
    category: {
      name: 'Phones',
      uri: 'phones',
      __typename: 'Category'
    }
}
```

A simple situation, but I can not understand what I'm doing wrong :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just do

```
<div class="container">
      <h1>
          {{(category$ | async)?.name}}
      </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Ohh Damn, Thank you so much:>

Comment: But how i can use it in component like this: `this.titleService.setTitle(this.category$.name);` ?

Comment: I think it will be something like `this.category$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe((category) => this.titleService.setTitle(category.name))`